# How to measure the time it took to sort an array for each sorting algorithms?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to create a program that measures the time it takes for each sorting algorithm to sort 50 random integers. The array not sorted is first printed and then the array sorted is printed. The output I get for each sorting algorithm when the time measured is 0. What could I change in my code to do this better?

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
      { 

      System.out.println("Please enter the size of array:");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
      int arraySize =input.nextInt(); 
      int[] array = new int[arraySize]; 
      if (arraySize == 50) {

        initValues();
        printValues();
        System.out.println("values is sorted: " + isSorted());
        System.out.println();

        // make call to sorting method here (just remove //)
         selectionSort();
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long total = 0; 
         long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long elapsedTime = stopTime-startTime;
         selectionSort(); 
         //bubbleSort();
         //shortBubble();
         //insertionSort();
         //mergeSort(0, SIZE - 1);
         //quickSort(0, SIZE - 1);
         //heapSort();


        printValues();
        System.out.println("values is sorted: " + isSorted());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The time it took to sort was: " +elapsedTime);
        }
      else {
      System.out.println("The size of the array should be 50"); 
      }
     }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the `stopTime` is at the correct location?

Comment: Looks like you take the `elapsedTime` and `stopTime` calculation before you actually do the sort. Your going to want to record those values *after* you have executed the code you wish to time.

Comment: I thought putting it after selectionSort() method is called would measure it correctly?  Where would I want to put it?

Comment: I have tried it this way and it doesn't work either:                           selectionSort();
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long total = 0; 
     selectionSort(); 
     long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long elapsedTime = stopTime-startTime;

Comment: To measure something, you want to capture time *before* operation (aka start time), and time *after* operation (aka end time). Right now you're doing both before, and your alternate comment is doing both after. And don't call `selectionSort()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to perform a micro benchmark correctly, but for a very simple start you can do this:

1. Don't use `currentTimeMillis`, use `nanoTime` instead for measuring elapsed time
2. Use a loop and perform the sort e.g. 10K times and measure that and then divide it by 10K etc